# Observer agreement in multilevel binary data

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, agreement-statistics, intraclass-correlation

I have a set of participants indicating with drawn circles where they experience pain on a manikin of the human body. These drawings were then independently rated by two human raters: each of 29 body areas was rated as "affected" or "not affected" according to a coding manual.

For such data, what would be an appropriate measure of observer agreement (that is, concordance of the two ratings, conditional on body area and participant)? I'm not sure whether Cohen's Kappa is because (a) the objects to be rated (body areas within participants) are not independent and (b) a very large proportion of these objects are not affected by pain, which may lead to an "overcorrection for chance" in Kappa (see http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8501467).

I was considering a 3-level hierarchical logistic mixed model of the following structure:

1. Rating
2. Body area
3. Participant

with random intercepts for Body Area and Participant, and then using the level 2 ICC:

$$
\frac{Var\left ( Body\; area \right ) + Var\left ( Participant \right )}{Var\left ( Rating \right ) + Var\left ( Body\; area \right ) + Var\left ( Participant \right )}
$$

as a measure of agreement. However, I'm not really sure about this model specification. In particular, since body areas are not randomly chosen, it would conceptually be more plausible to use a dummy-coded fixed effect for body area. Neither are the raters randomly chosen, so including a fixed effect for rater would also make sense. But then, does it even make sense to calculate the ICC as described above? Or are there other measures of agreement which make more sense?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: By the way, I wasn't even sure whether ICC can be calculated for a logistic mixed model to begin with. However the following reference seems to support that:

http://books.google.de/books?id=G8fhqL9xHOAC&pg=PA224 (Section 14.3.3)

Please correct me if I'm wrong though!

Comment: Why are the body areas not independent? Is it that if you have pain in one area you are likely to have pain in a nearby area or connected area?

Comment: Yes, that's what I am assuming. I didn't quantify the degree of dependence, though.
Actually I didn't even think about the question whether it would make more sense to assume a spatial autocorrelation instead of the compound symmetry of a standard random intercept model. I guess the former makes more sense although I have no clue whether it is possible to obtain an ICC for mixed models with spatial autocorrelation.

Comment: Before you go creating any crazy complex multilevel model, first think about what type of reliability you want: agreement or consistency. ICC, Cronbach's $\alpha$ and other metrics get at consistency: when I rate high, do you rate high? When I'm low, are you low? Even if we never agree. Agreement is different: kappa gives you that, as does Krippendorf's $\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint about Krippendorff's alpha, I hadn't heard of that before! As far as I know ICC can be calculated to quantify either agreement or consistency, see for example the paper by McGraw & Wong (1996), "Forming inferences about some intraclass correlation coefficients". In any case, I would also like to keep it simple, I'm just not sure which approach to take because there are so many metrics (and introductory texts advise you to choose the one which is appropriate to your data). A simple alternative would be to simply calculate Kappa after stratifying for body area I suppose...